# How to edit bibtex entry for a bimonthly IEEE journal?

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran, ieee-style

[IEEE bibtex style](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf) uses the following entry for a typical journal paper:

```
@article{foobar,
  author  = "A. Boo, C. Foo",
  title   = "Paper Title of His",
  journal = IEEE_J_IA,
  volume  = "40",
  month   = jan,
  year    = "2012",
  pages   = "1-11"
}
```

The journal "IEEE Transaction of Industry Applications" is bimonthly, so IEEE usually says "January-February 2012" ([example](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6112715)).  How do I edit the month field?  The following issues error

```
Warning--string name "jan/feb" is undefined
```

at compile time due to

```
month = jan/feb
```

Comment: I think this doesn't make any sense to have month names to point to the issue. Instead use issue number, many publications in fact delete/omit the month field since it hardly ever makes any difference. So `volume={48},
number={2},` defines unambiguously which issue is the publication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bibtex` allows  you to concatenate strings using `#`. Thus for a bimonthly issue of  journal you can use

```
month = jan # "/" # feb
```

See Section 2 of the `bibtex` manual (`texdoc bibtex`)